# Twitter API request_token Error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've spent days looking into this and I'm no further on.  I'm trying to allow users to log in to my .Net (MVC) website using Twitter.  It used to work, but at some point it stopped working on my production webserver (I've removed patches since I noticed it stopped working, but it still doesn't work).

The problem is the initial API call to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token.  On my localhost Windows 10 dev machine it works fine and it returns: oauth_token=xxx&oauth_token_secret=xxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

But on the webserver it returns a page of a poodle sat on a chair with an error 404!

I get the same issue with any library I use (TweetSharp, TweetInv, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter and even a manual HttpWebRequest!) so it isn't related to that.

It WORKS on my localhost (Visual Studio 2022).  It WORKS using Postman on my local machine AND on my web server.

It does NOT work on my web server (Server 2012 R2) via my website.

Because the libraries didn't work, I made a working Localhost example using HttpWebRequest so i could play around with headers etc to reflect Postman/Fiddler.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 

  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.Headers["Authorization"] = OAuthHeader;
  request.Accept = "*/*";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.KeepAlive = true;
  request.AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate);
```

Again, it worked locally but not on my web server.

My MVC site uses .net 4.8 (targetFramework="4.8").

I have added the URLs (localhost IP and my live domain callback URL) to my callback settings in the app settings.

I am using Oauth1.0a with read only permissions.

I've used IISCrypto to verify TLS1.2 is enabled, and it looks ok.

I'm running out of ideas!!  Has anyone got any pointers?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've run a simple CURL command as per below, and get the following:

[image]

Comment: Can you curl that URL via a terminal/powershell on the server to rule out any application code? Or is it that the machine can access it but not the code? Also what is the output of `nslookup api.twitter.com` on the server? Is this a self-managed web server or do you use a particular hosting solution? Is this server hosted on any cloud providers e.g. Azure / AWS?

Comment: Not sure how to use Curl, but I've used Postman on the server and that works?  And it works locally in IISExpress (Windows 10) but not on web server (IIS 6.2, Server 2012 R2).

Nslookup returns:
Name:    tpop-api.twitter.com
Address:  104.244.42.2
Aliases:  api.twitter.com

Also when i ran this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.twitter.com
It brought back 4 addresses (104.244.42.194,104.244.42.130,104.244.42.2,104.244.42.66)

My hosting is Server 2012 VPS (not Azure or AWS though)....

Comment: Correction - the webserver IIS is v8.5...

Comment: Okay so the VPS itself has connection to the API as well as Postman so it's not the machine itself - does the same *exact* (exact executable) work locally but not on the web server as a website?

Comment: It's not an executable.  It's an MVC website running on IIS 8.5...

Comment: @Captain_Planet Did you find the fix , I am also facing this issue since 1-2 week

Comment: Not yet....and Twitter support is a bit lame....i'm still investigating though!

Comment: @AbhinavGoyal, i fixed it with the following: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2022/06/07/twitter-api-giving-http-404-not-found-when-requesting-a-token/

Answer (score 0):

try checking with curl command like below from your server machine
[image: curl test of api url]

You need to ensure you are using TLS1.2 when you make calls to api.twitter.com - Twitter no longer supports the old TLS v1
If you get TLS issue try updating the Powershell on server machine to always use TLS1.2 by executing the command below:

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
I got the expected response instead of the 404 error.

```
PS C:\Users\onsolveadmin> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
PS C:\Users\onsolveadmin> curl https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token -v
VERBOSE: GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token with 0-byte payload
curl : {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
At line:1 char:1
+ curl https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token -v
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

that error went away and then make sure

from your code base you are ensuring it to use TLS1.2

for me these lines were causing issue , so I remove them  which I added back in 2019 to fix TLS issue itself
[image]

Comment: Please see image I've uploaded in my initial question above....

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it working after days of debugging.  It has something to do with Schannel/TLS/Cipher suites, but I'm not exactly sure what the specific fix was: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2022/06/07/twitter-api-giving-http-404-not-found-when-requesting-a-token/